# Server should shutdown when network connectivity goes down

Tags: linux, debian, scripting

I tried putting script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
date >> /home/date
halt
```

It works when the network cable removed manually and i have inserted the script in `/etc/network/if-down.d`. It is not working when the swtich is off. Can any one please tell me how to write script for this?

Comment: out of curiosity, why should a server halt when the network drops?

Comment: our client are facing a lot of power fluctuations, if the ups drained out in middle of night, the servers will shutdown abruptly so better to write a script that's the reason.

Comment: *That's* your solution?  You know, UPSes can tell the server that they're running out of power and it's time to shut down gracefully...

Comment: i know that, But that stupid ups provider has not given any cable to it... :-( otherwise i could've done like that..Please tell me how to write script.

Comment: I think for business purposes it might benefit you to do it right and spend whatever money is required to get the cable.  What type of UPS is it?

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously a rather ugly hack. But you could put a script into crontab that periodically checks for network & shuts down the system if it's no longer there. Sort of a Dead man's Switch.

Comment: you're right, that *is* an ugly hack.  +1, i like it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting your script in `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/`?

Comment: Yeah! I tried it, But did'nt work.. :(

Comment: I don't see how this could work. AFAIK, `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` is called if the network connection is shut down locally (by calling the approriate shutdown programs/scripts). It is not invoked if the network just dies for reasons outside the local system.

Answer (score 0):

is the script chmodded as executable?

```
chmod +x /etc/network/if-down.d/*scriptname*
```

Comment: Yeah!! without that script will not run.. :) i have done..